# If I had lots of money (A)/I would give some to anybody (B)/ who asked for it (C)/No Error (D)

Tags: conditional-constructions, exam-questions

> If I had lots of money (A)/I would give some to anybody (B)/ who asked for it (C)/No Error (D)

If the above sentence correct ? Generally the structure /construction is to use *would have* with *had* e.g. If he had seen you he would have stopped the car. But I guess *had* here in above given sentence is acting as main verb so it fine to use *would* without have in part B of sentence, but what about part C, is that correct ? Perhaps since its a wish of present its better to use *asks* instead of *asked*, Am I correct ?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Don't know why you search for these questions and go as per their solutions, if those solutions were reliable then I , myself could have resolved my doubt by a simple google search, Those searches aren't 'official' solution and as I told earlier 99% of them are wrong, that's the reason I post my doubts here on SE. Moreover It's not Indian Civil service exam, so please don't mention that.

Comment: In English, we don't use the noun "doubt" to mean "question". Please consult an English language dictionary to learn about the meaning of "doubt". There is _no error_ in the sentence _"If I had lots of money I would give some to anybody who asked for it."_ We really can't help you with the imaginary version of the language in which these exams are written. (And of course the "Staff Selection Commission" (SSC), from whose exam this question is taken, selects for the civil service.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant Neither did I ask answer for any sort of imaginary version of the language nor did I mention any such source in my question, It's you who are mentioning it in all my question. I simply put my question hoping to get a answer. In third comment you are mentioning that the there is no error in this sentence, In the first comment itself you could have mentioned that instead of making such hue and cry.

Comment: If the source provided in the edit is incorrect, please replace it with the actual source. Our purpose here is to help visitors learn English, and we want to help you as well. If you are being provided with inaccurate lessons, the best thing we can do to help you is to point that out.

Comment: FYI Indian Civil service exam is conducted by UPSC not SSC. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Services_Examination_(India)

Comment: Good! Thank you for the correction. I ought to have said "government service". In any case, whatever the "SSC" selects for, it does so with an exam written in a language that has little in common with English. Why not choose material written by English speakers? Would this not be of greater benefit to you than this stuff?

Comment: Please include a link to the source of your question.

Comment: No Error (D). The structure of the main example is different from the example in your explanation. In (A),  "had" is the verb. In "If he had seen you...", "had seen" is the verb. So "had" usage is main verb vs. helper verb.

Comment: @P.E.Dant There is no rule mentioned on ELL SE that I have to mention sources if I have to ask a question here. If any how it was relevant to this question I would have mentioned it myself. Moreover as you told the purpose of the forum is to help learn English language not to misguide learners by pointing them to 'incorrect' and 'unofficial' keys and solutions which you are doing in all my question. Any tom dick and harry can buy a domain in a few bucks and put up a website claiming its own Key to the questions. My question is complete on its own and doesn't necessarily needs a source.

Comment: @user3169 Thankyou so much for a straightforward answer.

Comment: There is no "rule" involved. Adding a source makes it easier to provide a useful answer, especially in the case of "exam" questions, and those which cite journalism and literature. I'm not sure what _"few a domain in a few bucks"_ means. You might benefit from reading this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/28932/37009

Answer (score -1):

Option D, No Improvement.

'Had' is used as the main verb and hence 'would + v1' is absolutely correct, also the sentence is in past, therefore, 'asked' is also correct and hence, no improvement.